# What are the main use cases of Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

I've read about **data properties** in Javascript Textbook and imagine using `Object.defineProperty` only in conjunction with **accessor properties**.

What are the other main use cases of Object.defineProperty to set attributes: `[[Enumerable]]`, `[[Writable]]`, `[[Configurable]]`? Is it used in frameworks? For what reasons? Is it used in client applications?

Comment: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is generally very insightful and talks to use cases.

Comment: Main use case is to define a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty` in general is useful to copy property descriptors from one object to another with the related methods `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`, e.g. when merging things into a prototype.

And as you already mentioned they can be used for getters and setters. The object literal syntax only works when creating new objects. To create new getters/setters in an existing object (e.g. a prototype) you have to use `Object.defineProperty()`, or copy over the descriptors, as mentioned above.

> [[Enumerable]]

Useful to avoid enumeration via `Object.keys()`, for ... in loops, adding properties to array subclasses and the like.
This is quite important when adding polyfills to built-in prototypes, especially `Object.prototype` since you don't want your added methods to suddenly show up in loops as it could break other code which does not do the `.hasOwnProperty()` check.

> [[Writable]], [[Configurable]]

Those are not really "useful" in the sense of enabling new programming styles, but they are sanity features that allow you to create read-only properties that can't be overwritten or removed by accident. So yeah, it's great for libraries.

`Object.freeze()` / `.seal()` / `.preventExtensions()` expand this kind of protection further to the point where you could protect objects sufficiently to create somewhat secure javascript eval sandboxes by protecting the prototypes of of built-in objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "getters and setters don't have a dedicated syntax in ES5"?

Comment: `freeze`/`seal`/`preventExtensions` is [very much ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.8) as well.

Comment: Ah right, I was thinking of method shorthand declarations. I'll edit that